# XML format in Kobo Sqlite database for bookmarks

Tags: xml, adobe, epub

I am to extract bookmarks from an `.epub.annot` file from a Kobo ebook reader. It is an xml file with annotations, and the annotations have a tag `fragment` with the following as an example:

```
<fragment
   start="OEBPS/9781118087220c07.xhtml#point(/1/4/2/134/1:2)"
   end="OEBPS/9781118087220c07.xhtml#point(/1/4/2/134/1:100)"
progress="0">
```

Some said that this is a [epub canonical fragment identifier](http://www.idpf.org/epub/linking/cfi/) but another person noted that this is better [Adobe RMSDK](https://www.adobe.com/hu/solutions/ebook/rmsdk.html) which does not have an open description.

What does this

```
(/1/4/2/134/1:2)
```

and

```
(/1/4/2/134/1:100)
```

mean?

The very last number seems to be a character count as I inspected the database but the other numbers' role is less clear.

EDIT: the header of the xml file is this:

```
<annotationSet xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
   xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/digitaleditions/annotations">
```

The purl.org link gave a file with xml namespace description but it did not include the `fragment` tag, while the adobe link was broken. I searched for "adobe annotations xml" but in vain.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately